# Extract string following another string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, design-patterns

I have the following string:

> [1360308597] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;demo-jms2;OutConnectorResponse;notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL ConsumerCount=0[1360308817] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;demo-jms2;Disk Space;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;DISK CRITICAL - free space: /data 3018 MB (10% inode=92%):

In the above string I want to extract the string following `demo-jms2`. Here `demo-jms2` occurs twice. I want to get all words following `demo-jms2` so the answer should be 
`OutConnectorResponse` and `Disk Space`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is  [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=demo-jms2;)[^;]+' file
OutConnectorResponse
Disk Space
```

Options:

> -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
>
> -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN

Explanation:

```
(?<=demo-jms2;) # Positive lookbehind: match the follow after literal demo-jms2;
[^;]+           # Match one or more non ; characters
```

**Edit:**

To filter duplicates from the results pipe through `sort -u`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=demo-jms2;)[^;]+' file 
OutConnectorResponse
Disk Space
OutConnectorResponse
Disk Space

$ grep -Po '(?<=demo-jms2;)[^;]+' file | sort -u
Disk Space
OutConnectorResponse
```

Comment: Hi Sudo, How can I remove duplicates from this grep? if Disk Space comes 2 times...

Comment: Hi Sudo,How can I separate the result with comma? for eg : Disk Space,OutConnectorResponse